# Laravel Eloquent Relationships for Siblings

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationships

Relationship for Siblings are many to many self relationship. So, for many to many self relationship, we can define two functions in the model:

```
public function siblings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'student_sibling', 'student_id', 'sibling_id');
}

public function siblingOf()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'student_sibling', 'sibling_id', 'student_id');
}
```

The first one returns the students who are siblings of the student. The reverse is also true for siblings. So, the second one returns the students of whom the student is a sibling.

So, we can merge both the collections to get a list of students who are siblings of the student. Here is my code in the controller method:

```
    $siblingOf = $student->siblingOf;

    $siblings = $student->siblings;

    $siblings = $siblings->merge($siblingOf);
```

But there is more. Siblings relationship is a chain relationship unlike friends relationship. This mean, if X is a sibling of Y and Y is a sibling of Z, then Z is a sibling of X.

So, how to get the collection of all students who are sibling of a student?

Comment: So it's more like `relative` not `sibling`, right? How deep you'd like it to be? Mind that it can become something like `each student is everyone else's relative in a way`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a Student model, with student_id as your primary key, and a pivot table that looks something like this:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| id (PK) | student_id | sibling_id |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 1       | 1          | 2          |
| 2       | 2          | 1          |
| 3       | 3          | 4          |
| 4       | 4          | 2          |
| 5       | 6          | 5          |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

In this example, we want to be able to discern that 1, 2, 3 and 4 are all siblings of each other. 5 and 6 are siblings as well.

One way to solve this is by gathering the result of the two `belongsToMany()` relationships in your model—as you did in your question—and then recursively iterating over the result, continuing to check the `belongsToMany()` functions until we run out of siblings.

In the Student model, define two functions:

```php
public function getAllSiblings(){

    // create a collection containing just the first student
    $this->siblings = $this->newCollection()->make($this);

    // add siblings (recursively) to the collection
    $this->gatherSiblings($this->student_id);

    // OPTIONAL: remove the first student, if desired
    $this->siblings->shift();

    return($this->siblings);
}

private function gatherSiblings($student_id){

    $checkStudent = Student::find($student_id);

    if ($checkStudent) {
        // get related siblings from model, combine them into one collection
        $siblingOf = $checkStudent->siblingOf()->get();
        $siblings = $checkStudent->siblings()->get();
        $siblings = $siblings->merge($siblingOf);

        // iterate over the related siblings
        $siblings->each(function($sibling)
        {
            // if we've found a new sibling who's 
            // not already in the collection, add it
            if(!$this->siblings->contains($sibling->student_id)) {
                $this->siblings->push($sibling);

                // look for more siblings (recurse)
                $this->gatherSiblings($sibling->student_id);
            };
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

In your controller, find the initial student, and then call `getAllSiblings()` from Student:

```php
$student = Student::find($id);
$siblings = $student->getAllSiblings();
```

The result is a collection with all the siblings of the original student. So, if you run this for student 1, you will get a collection containing students 2, 3 and 4. (If you'd prefer to keep the original student as part of the siblings collection, so that running this for 1 returns 1, 2, 3 and 4, simply remove the `optional` step in `getAllSiblings()`.)

From there, you can cast the collection to an array, or sort, etc. as needed.

Comment: You don't need this piece of code, just call `with` on the relation to make it recursive. However this is not the way to go, as it may easily exceed function nesting limit.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk can you demonstrate solving this using `with`? I can't see how it would retrieve anything beyond the first set of siblings. How would `with` traverse the whole chain of siblings? (And real world limitations would prevent this from recursing more than, say, a dozen times.)

Comment: there you go mate. And tell me, what do you mean by `real world limitations would prevent..` ?

Comment: Cool, but causing an infinite loop (which using the recursive `with` does) doesn't solve the problem. (And real world limitations, based on the specifics of the question, mean it's not likely a student has more than, say, a dozen siblings. Maybe 20. Certainly less than infinite.)

Comment: You misunderstood. It's not the methods itself that causes the error, it's the relation. Imagine these ids are related: `1-2, 2-3, 3-1` - this will make it infinite. And for real world limitations - as you can see I asked OP if he meant **relatives**, because obviously, you can't have a sibling, who has another sibling not being your sibling as well. So for relatives, it's pretty easy to, again, call infinite loop, unless you explicitly limit it to given nesting level.

Comment: I get that, but your case `1-2, 2-3, 3-1` seems to be exactly the type of condition the OP is trying to deal with. I may have read it wrong, but based on his setup, it seems like he's dealing with a table where each student row has **one** entry for a sibling, and he's trying to walk the "chain" of all these incomplete sibling relationships in order to gather them all. I'm assuming here that he did, in fact, mean siblings, not relatives.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive relation could do this, **BUT it will probably cause infinite loop (function nesting limit error)**.

Anyway this is how to setup such relation:

```
public function siblingsRecursive()
{
    return $this->siblings()->with('siblingsRecursive');
}

public function siblings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'siblings');
}
```

Then you call, as simple as this:

```
$students = Student::with('siblingsRecursive');
```

Comment: I think using Eager Loading recursively could be dangerous in the application I am building. Because, there is no way to know that the siblings of the current student in the recursion has already been found. So, in some cases, it will cause infinite loop. Thank you for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might want is this:

```
 public function siblings() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'parent_id');
 }
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, thank you