# Laravel Eloquent "siblings" as a relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```php
class PageRelation extends Eloquent
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'page_relation';
    protected $casts = [
            'parent' => 'int', // FK to page
            'child' => 'int',  // FK to page
            'lpc' => 'int',
        ];

    protected $fillable = [
            'lpc',
        ];

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'category_id', 'child');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'category_id', 'parent');
    }

    public function siblings()
    {
        // ...  return $this->hasMany(Page::class ...
        // how do I define this relationship?
    }
}
```

In my design a `sibling` is (as you might expect) a record that shares the same `parent` but not itself (exclude current `child`). How can I achieve this?

This is not a duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent Relationships for Siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821929/laravel-eloquent-relationships-for-siblings) because 1) the structure is different, 2) I would like to return a relationship, not a query result, I know how to query this, but I want the power of eager loader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent Relationships for Siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821929/laravel-eloquent-relationships-for-siblings)

Comment: Can you please describe your relationships, maybe it is easier with a different structure. I kind of doubt that same can be achieved through polymorphic relationship.

Comment: @Ruman `PageRelation` is a pivot table to `Page` which I hope is very clear by it's few columns and the parents and children relationship I have already defined. I just want all the Pages that share the same parent(s). As for polymorphic relationships: that is really the wrong solution, they are for relationships from 1 table to N other tables, using the same column.

Comment: Ok got it, I was thinking about something else.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: @ThomasMoors Can one child have multiple parents? and what is lpc field?

Comment: @JithinJose Yes they can have multiple parents. Lpc is not important for this question, but they are used for special kinds of navigation on the site: it will produce an alternative breadcrumb for a page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with Laravel's in-built relations. What I would suggest doing is creating your own relation type that extends `HasMany` and use that.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class HasManySiblings extends HasMany
{    
    public function addConstraints()
    {
        if (static::$constraints) {
            if (is_null($foreignKeyValue = $this->getParentKey())) {
                $this->query->whereNull($this->foreignKey);
            } else {
                $this->query->where($this->foreignKey, '=', $foreignKeyValue);
                $this->query->whereNotNull($this->foreignKey);
            }

            $this->query->where($this->localKey, '!=', $this->parent->getAttribute($this->localKey));
        }
    }

    public function getParentKey()
    {
        return $this->parent->getAttribute($this->foreignKey);
    }
}
```

By extending the `HasMany` class and providing your own implementation of `addConstraints` you are able to control what gets added to the query for related models. Usually, what Laravel would do here is add `where parent_id = <your model ID>` but I've changed it here to add `where parent_id = <your model PARENT ID>` (if your model's `parent_id` is `null` it will instead add `where parent_id is null`). I've also added an extra clause to ensure that the calling model is not included in the resulting collection: `and id != <your model ID>`.

You can use it like this in your `Page` model:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    public function siblings()
    {
        return new HasManySiblings(
            $this->newRelatedInstance(Page::class)->newQuery(), $this, 'parent_id', 'id'
        );
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to load the siblings like this:

```
$page = Page::find(1);
dd($page->siblings);
```

Please note though, I have only tested this for retrieving related models and it may not work when using the relation for other purposes such as saving related models etc.

Also, please note that in my examples above I've used `parent_id` instead of `parent` as in your question. Should be straight swap though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it works with your model which is kinda marginal because you are relating same objects with a middle table. But,

```
hasManyThrough()
```

could be a solution for this.

*"... has many siblings through parent."*

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: not gonna work because you cannot exclude subject from results

Answer (score 0):

This is off-topic but bare me with this. I have this suggestion for the way you are handling these relations. You don't need `PageRelation` model, you can define `belongsToMany` relation on `Page` model directly. Moreover, you dont need extra attribute `parent`, this is kind of inconsistent, defining parent and child both, only children are enough to determine parents. So Instead of two seperate columns, You can reverse the keys when you retrieve the relation. Let me show you with an example what I mean:

```
pages:
keep this table intact

pages_relation:
- id
- page_id (foreign key to id on page)
- child_id (foreign key to id on page)
```

And then define two relations in your model:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Page', 'pages_relation', 'page_id', 'child_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Page', 'pages_relation', 'child_id', 'page_id');
    }
}
```

You can stick to whatever feels good to you. But, I feel this is more consistent. As, there is only single source of truth. 
If A is a child of B, then B has to be a parent of A, its obvious, only "A is child of B" is enough to state "B is a parent of A".

I have tested this, it works very well.

**EDIT**
You can extend `BelongsToMany` relation to get `BelongsToManySiblings` realtionship, and just override the `addWhereConstraints` method.

```
class BelongsToManySiblings extends BelongsToMany
{
    protected function addWhereConstraints()
    {
        $parentIds = \DB::table($this->table)
            ->select($this->foreignPivotKey)
            ->where($this->relatedPivotKey, '=', $this->parent->{$this->parentKey})
            ->get()->pluck($this->foreignPivotKey)->toArray();

        $this->query->whereIn(
            $this->getQualifiedForeignPivotKeyName(),
            $parentIds
        )->where(
            $this->getQualifiedRelatedPivotKeyName(),
            '<>',
            $this->parent->{$this->parentKey}
        )->groupBy($this->getQualifiedRelatedPivotKeyName());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then you can add `siblings` relationship method on your `Page` model:

```
public function siblings()
{
    return new BelongsToManySiblings(
        $this->newRelatedInstance(Page::class)->newQuery(),
        $this,
        'pages_relation',
        'parent_id',
        'child_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        $this->guessBelongsToManyRelation()
    );
}
```

**Note:**  *This case does not work for eager loads, eager load needs overriding `match` and `addEagerContraints` methods on the `BelongsToManySiblings` class. You can peek the `BelongsToMany` class on laravel source to see an example how it eager loads the relations.*

Comment: I see your relations, but those are parents and children. How would you do the siblings?

Comment: You can, use Jonathan's logic but in this case you would extend a `BelongsToMany` relation. If you want, I can extend my answer.